# Spring Hibernate Connection through AOP standalone application

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop

I am trying to develop Annotation based Spring Hibernate standalone application to connect to DB. I've gone through the some blogs and wondered like we should not make use of hibernateTemplate becoz coupling your application tightly to the spring framework. For this reason, Spring recommends that HibernateTemplate no longer be used.Further more my requirement is changed to Spring Hibernate with AOP using Declarative Transaction management.I am new to AOP concepts. Can any one please give an example on Spring Hibernate Connection through AOP. That would be a great help to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so as to make clear what exactly you want to know. You have not really asked anything or explained your requirements well enough IMO. I also edited your question because of bogus formatting (your whole text was formatted as code and looked like a one-liner with a long horizontal scrollbar). Please be a bit more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for exemples of project structures, you may want to use maven archetypes which provide you an already working Spring + Hibernate or Spring + JPA configuration.
They may provide you also a web layer (or not) but you can remove it if you want.

To try that, install maven and type:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

By the way, I don't think using HibernateTemplate is a big deal. Many people still use it. But you'd better inject the `Hibernate` session factory and use contextual sessions with `getCurrentSession()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use JPA instead of plain Hibernate. You can of course use Hibernate as a provider. I guess that you know how to run Spring container in standalone application. Just follow the steps from documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa). Use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Then [read about transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-tx).

There is a new feature that lets you start JPA without `persistence.xml` file. [Read here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-jpa-without-xml).

If you still want to use plain Hibernate [follow the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate).